# git help log on windows powershell is opening a html page in browser instead of showing it on the browser

Tags: git

I am using **powershell** on windows for the command **git help log**. I want to see the help content on the console itself. But instead it downloads a page and shows it up in the browser. What should I do to make it display on the console itself?

[image]

Comment: Are you using git for windows? What is the relevance of mentioning power shell (does git help work as desired in a cmd prompt) ?

Comment: I am just using powershell instead of cmd. No particular significance. I did not check with cmd. I just checked with cmd. its the same behavior.

Comment: Ok, then I would say without following the instructions linked in my answer, out of the box it may not be possible to do what you wish.

Answer (score 5):

This is usually set with `git config --global help.format <web|man|info>`.

However, the man pages are not part of the Git for Windows bundle so only 'web' works.

The alternative would be to install Cygwin and then git using it. That has the 'man' help that you wish to see.

#### Installing man pages for git for windows

Apparently it is possible : http://bitsandnucleotides.tumblr.com/post/58929593915/response-to-the-question-man-pages-for-git-bash

However looking at those instructions I think if you wish to see 'man' help then Cygwin git is the simpler way to go about it.